How do I determine whether this DRV8210 IC can be included in my PCB design?
I am a complete newbie to PCB design. I would like to design a motor drive board that I can use to control 3 DC brushed motors at once. The voltage and current rating for the motor is 9-12V and 1.2A. So, I found a chip called DRV8210, which is a 12V 1.76A H-bridge.
My question is: How do I know that I can include this chip into my PCB? My ultimate goal is to send my design to a PCB assembly service to get it manufactured. As long as the chip is not discontinued, is it safe to assume that the PCB assembly service will be able to get the chip?

Are you dead set on using an assembly service, or would you consider assembling it yourself? I can't help with assembly services--never used one--but I wanted to make sure you're aware that it's not the only option.

I'm pretty sure if an assembly service can't source a chip you specify, though, you can always source it yourself and send it to them. Just talk to them about it.

I am pretty certain that I want to use an assembly service because I think learning PCB design will help in the future. So when you custom manufacture a PCB, do you just get the circuit without any of the parts (resistor, capacitor, chip, etc) and you need to buy the parts and put them on?

A PCB assembly service will will assemble components onto a PCB for you. If you order PCBs without assembly you get just the bare PCBs.

@jlee PCB design and assembly are two different things. An assembly service puts the parts onto the PCB; a PCB fab just makes the PCB itself, and then you put the parts on, or send them on to an assembly house.

@Hearth is right. If you are able to source the component, the assembly house will be able to. Either directly, or through you. Just ask them.
